# Error con url amigable - no se puede ver las pagina

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo un problema con url amigable. La pagina que muestra los resultados y este es el error:

> Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404
>   localhost
>   Apache/2.4.38 (Unix) PHP/7.3.3

Los archivos que tengo son:

```
oficinaUno
  |_ index.php
  |_ task
       |_ view.php
  |_ .htaccess
```

En el index la `url` de la tarea es:

```
<a href="task/<?=$row['id'];?>"> // $row['id'] viene de la base de datos
```

Dentro del directorio `task` el archivo view.php recibe el id por `get`

```
<?php
$id_tarea = $_GET['id'];
echo $id_tarea;
?>
```

El archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

Rewriterule ^task/(.+)/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)/(.+)$ view.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haríá de la siguiente manera, para que redirija al archivo view dentro de la carpeta task.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Rewriterule ^task/(.+)$ /task/view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Gracias Skatox, pero el error continua. Estuve buscando y tambien lei que habia que habilitar `mod_rewrite` en `httpd.conf`, lo cual, ya estaba habilitado y aun asi no funciona.